# Yii2 SluggableBehavior "attribute" or "value" property must be specified error

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I follow [Programming with YII2 tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/programming-with-yii2--cms-725) on tuts+ but when I finish chapter [Programming With Yii2: Sluggable Behavior](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-sluggable-behavior--cms-23222) and try to visit `/status/` page i see next error message
[image: error message]

Model where i connect to SluggableBehavior

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;


class Status extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const PERMISSIONS_PRIVATE = 10;
    const PERMISSIONS_PUBLIC = 20;

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'message',
                // 'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
            ],
        ];
    }
    . . .
```

What i'm doing wrong? I read definitive guide and example of usage in SluggableBehavior class in yii2 directory, but not found anything special.

Comment: i can't find any example with `'value'` specified using of this behavior, that very strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours of reading docs and forums about yii2 and sluggable behavior i found what i need.

I specify `value` property and all works fine:

```
'value' => function($event){
    if(!empty($event->sender->slug))
        return $event->sender->slug;
    return Inflector::slug($event->sender->title);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it was correct, but I hade the same issue but for other reason. I've tried to merge parent behaviour and current model behaviour and by mistake to forgot one level brackets `[]`

```
  public function behaviors() {
    return array_merge(parent::behaviors(),
      [  // <-- forgot this brackets
        [
          'class'=> \yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior::className(),
          'attribute'=> ['singleTranslation.title'],
          'immutable' => true,
          'ensureUnique' => true,
          //'slugAttribute' => 'slug'
        ]
      ]  // <-- forgot this brackets
    );
  }
```